# Spring Boot Oauth Custom Login Form

Tags: spring, security, authentication, spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I followed the spring tutorial "SSO with OAuth2: Angular JS and Spring Security Part V".

I converted the "authserver"-project from maven to gradle after that the custom login form doesn't work anymore.

Are the wro tasks in the pom.xml needed for the login form to work?

I also tried this tutorial but it didn't work in my scenario either: 
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/guides/form.html

I hope that you can help me.

**Logfile:**

2016-05-18 11:14:53.667 DEBUG 22312 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 5 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2016-05-18 11:14:53.667 DEBUG 22312 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /logout
2016-05-18 11:14:53.667 DEBUG 22312 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 6 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2016-05-18 11:14:53.667 DEBUG 22312 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Request 'GET /login' doesn't match 'POST /login
2016-05-18 11:14:53.667 DEBUG 22312 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /login at position 7 of 14 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: '**DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter**'
2016-05-18 11:14:53.667 DEBUG 22312 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.

Code in the **OAuth2ServerConfiguration**:

```
   @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
            .and().requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and().authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }
```

**MainAuthserverApplication.java**:
`@ComponentScan`
`@SessionAttributes("authorizationRequest")
@EnableAutoConfiguration()`
@EnableConfigurationProperties({AuthProperties.class})
`public class MainAuthserverApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {`

```
@Override
public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    registry.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
    registry.addViewController("/oauth/confirm_access").setViewName("authorize");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed the problem myself:

It seems that these two methods have to be in the same class:

```
@Configuration
@Order(-20)
protected static class LoginConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {


        // @formatter:off
        http.formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().and().requestMatchers()
            .antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access").and().authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.parentAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }
}
```

Comment: hi jens could you pls share your work on github. i have done same but mine is not working